# CodeIgniter Gmaps get marker object lat long

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, google-maps

I'm using the Google Maps CI library by [biostall](http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library). I want to panTo the marker that has been clicked so the map is centered on that marker.

I've tried this JS but it seems that the marker object doesn't have the getLatLng() method.

```
function open_marker(id){
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id],'click'); // this works fine, opens the correct marker
    map.panTo(markers[id].getLatLng());
    return;
}
```

Getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #V> has no method 'getLatLng'

I need to get a marker object that I can getLatLng().

When I `alert(markers[id])` it says object, so I'm assuming it exists.

Comment: Object may exist but that says nothing about its methods as the output error says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getLatLng()` was in API v2

in API v3 use `getPosition()` instead

for all options and methods see [Google Maps Javascript API V3 Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)